# URL Redirect Via HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm starting a blog on a domain which I have just purchased and would like to set up another blog as a subdomain.

Now if this secondary blog takes off as well as I hope it does in the near future I'd like to set it up on a domain of it's own, but I'm wondering how easy it is to redirect people who have the existing url to the new one.

I have a folder structure like this:

```
domain.com >>> htaccess . index.php . about.php . blog/ . features/
```

My `Blog` and `Features` folders also contain a `htaccess` file and their own `index` page + other relevant php pages.

I was wondering if you could redirect people to the new domain using only the primary `htaccess` file, which is located under the main `domain.com` folder, or if you'd have to edit the htaccess within each sub folder.

What would be the best way of doing this, and to some extent, how would this be done successfully?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ http://new-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]` That is it

Comment: And this goes in the **Primary** htaccess? Meaning I would be able to delete all other files and folders and just have one `htaccess` located in the subdomain?

Comment: Brilliant! Was dreading the thought of having to create a load of redirections once the website was established. Thanks HJ

Comment: be careful.  That rule will redirect everything, including queries for your main blog. What you want is to redirect only requests to your subdomain.  For that you need a rewrite condition (redirect only when a condition is met) See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you would need to do is use the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newblog.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So when someone accesses the old domain, it would direct to the new one.

Comment: be careful. That rule will redirect everything, including queries for your main blog. What you want is to redirect only requests to your subdomain. For that you need a rewrite condition (redirect only when a condition is met) See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Once you move your subdomain `sub.mydomain.com` to `newdomain.com`, you can use htaccess `mod_rewrite` module to redirect queries from the subdomain to the new domain. You would put the rules in the top level htaccess file that controls the old domain.  With the example domains above, it would be something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
# turn on mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# only redirect if query is for the sub domain (non case-sensitive match)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]

# rewrite all urls (that match the subdomain host) to new domain, 
# be sure to include the original path and query string
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

If your new domain doesn't use `www` prefix, just remove that from the rewrite rule.  `QSA` tells the server to send along the query string (part of the url after the `?` character).  `L` means stop processing htaccess document. `R=301` means to tell the browser that from then on it can go directly to `newdomain.com` whenever the user tries to go to `sub.mydomain.com`

Comment: So with this, if a user goes to say `http://old-domain.com/features/interviews/1111/an-interview-with-a-band`, they will automatically be redirected to `http://new-domain.com/features/interviews/1111/an-interview-with-a-band`?

Comment: Not exactly. You said in the OP that you wanted to redirect only the secondary blog from the subdomain to the new site (without redirecting the main blog from the base domain) right? A user who goes to `old_domain.com` wouldn't be redirected (she wouldn't meet the `RewriteCond` condition, but a user who goes to `subdomain.old_domain.com` would be redirected.  In addition, the rule above would preserve the query string, unlike thickguru's answer. `subdomain.olddomain.com/path?post=123` should be redirected to `newdomain.com/path?post=123`.  That's why I have the `QSA` flag after the rule.

Comment: You dont need to use the QSA here. QSA is helpful when the target path also contains a query string then it combines them.

Comment: Yes but that was just one example `REQUEST_URI`. If you move one domain to another, what are the chances that none of the URLs have a query string?  Seems to me it makes sense to include QSA even though it wouldn't make a difference for the specific URL asked about.